# ELK metricbeat connection error

Tags: elastic-stack

I am getting one error on installed metricbeat connection from Windows server to the linux server with the following error.
"Connecting error publishing events (retrying): Get http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200: dial tcp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Is your machine hosting elasticsearch (linux server) reachable from your Windows Server?

Try telnet linux server on port 9200 from windows server